# xkb Can't find file "myswap" for symbols include error in systemd python job

Tags: bash, systemd, python, xkb

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and python 2.7.
I've got a bash script which overwrites default keyboard bindings and it always works when I execute it from terminal, here's the script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

xkbcomp -w0 -I$HOME/.xkb $HOME/.xkb/keymap/mykbd $DISPLAY
```

I've also added it to my `.bashrc` file so that it executes always when I open a new terminal.
The problem is that I have a standing desk and sometimes when I adjust the height the keyboard is disconnected and connected again and I have to open a new terminal again so that my custom keybindings are applied again.

The best solution that I came up with is to create a systemd python job that will execute the bash script when my keyboard is plugged in.
When I run the python script by itself it very rarely works, I can see in syslog that the python script calls the bash script when the keyboard is disconnected and connected again and the keybindings are overwritten but the new keybindings don't work.
Here's the python script

```py
 #!/usr/bin/python                                                           
 
 import functools
 import os.path
 import pyudev
 import subprocess
 
 def main():
     BASE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
     path = functools.partial(os.path.join, BASE_PATH)
     call = lambda x, *args: subprocess.call([path(x)] + list(args))
 
     context = pyudev.Context()
     monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
     monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
 
     monitor.start()
 
     for device in iter(monitor.poll, None):
         name = 'Freestyle_Edge_Keyboard'
 
         if device.get('ID_MODEL') == name:
             subprocess.call(['sh', '/home/user/scripts/loadKeyboardOverwrites.sh'])
 
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

When I start the systemd job I can see in syslog that the keys are overwritten but it doesn't work and the only thing in syslog that I find a bit suspicious is the message about `xkb_variant & xkb_options requires a string value` and error about `myswap`

```
Mar 24 21:33:32 user callShOnKeyboardPlugin.py[1533582]: Error:            Can't find file "myswap" for symbols include
Mar 24 21:33:32 user callShOnKeyboardPlugin.py[1533582]:                   Exiting
Mar 24 21:33:32 user callShOnKeyboardPlugin.py[1533582]:                   Abandoning symbols file "(null)"
Mar 24 21:17:01 user /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[28481]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Mar 24 21:17:01 user /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[28481]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "sk"
Mar 24 21:17:01 user /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[28481]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Mar 24 21:17:01 user /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[28481]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
```

The myswap file is located in ~/.xkb/symbols/myswap

Here's the systemd job

```
[Unit]
Description=desc

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/scripts/callShOnKeyboardPlugin.py
Restart=always
Environment="PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Does anyone have any idea where the issue could be please? Or is there any other better way how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
If there's something missing please let me know and I'll provide it.

---

**Update**

I handled it in a different way. I've set it up as a startup script and also I've added a bit of delay after when the keyboard was detected and that made it work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to set `WorkingDirectory = /home/user`. Are you sure `$DISPLAY` is set correctly? Might be worth trying to dump your environment from the unit and compare that to your regular shell environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry that I didn't notice it sooner, I handled it in a different way. I've set it up as a startup script and also I've added a bit of delay after when the keyboard was detected and that made it work consistently.